# Do invalid Google AMP pages still show up in search results?

Tags: amp-html

Despite reading the AMP documentation and scouring message boards, I'm still unclear what happens to an AMP page if it fails validation. It certainly won't appear in the AMP stories carousel -- but will invalid AMP pages still be indexed by Google and appear in regular ol' search results? Or will only the "full" version specified in `rel="canonical"` appear?

I ask because there are some times when I actually want a page to fail AMP validation (for example, if I'm putting an interactive map that includes inline JavaScript on a page). In that case, I only want Google to index the full version, not a broken, half-functional AMP version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invalid AMPs won't show up in Google Search at all, neither in the top stories carousel nor the 'normal' search results.

In case you're intentionally publishing invalid AMPs, I recommend removing the AMP attribute from `<html amp>`. In this case your pages will continue to work, but won't be recognized as AMP.

However, you can easily embed interactive maps via iframe, [here](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-iframe/#google-maps) is a sample for Google Maps.

Comment: A follow-up: An invalid AMP page won't have any effect on the ability of the page's full version (that is, what's specified in `rel="canonical"`) to be indexed by Google, right?